# I am using FTP npm to transfer my local file to remote server. the below code is not responding. Any error? or something else

Tags: node.js, ftp

```
 var c = new Client();
  c.on('ready', function() {
    c.put('foo.txt', 'foo.remote-copy.txt', function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      c.end();
    });
});
```

I am using FTP npm to transfer my local file to remote server. the below code is not responding. Any error? or something else .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling `c.connect()`? [The docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp#methods) say that this function takes an object as an argument with all of your parameters. the default is to connect to `localhost:21` as `anonymous`.

Comment: I am passing the object containing server credentials as argument

Comment: See this code.. Please tell if you want to see any other code

Comment: var ftpConfig = {
    host: '***********',
    port: 21,
    user: '*****',
    password: '***********',
    mode: 'Active'
}
client.connect(ftpConfig);
client.on('ready', function () {
    client.put(req.file.path, './' + req.file.filename,function(ftpErr) {
        if (ftpErr) {
        }else {
            client.end();
            cb(null)
        }
    });